# modal is not a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

When I answered `true` it shows me an error:

> modal is not a function

When `false` it displays the HTML fine. I do not understand why `html()` works but not `modal()`.

```
$('#conxModal').modal('toggle'); // Work here    
function postProcessing(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val == true) {
                $('#conxModal').modal('toggle');
            }
            if (val == false)   {
                $("span#erreurcnx").html('bad');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The script which contains the `modal()` function hasn't been loaded properly

Comment: ... as jquery and javascript has no modal() method throws error.

Comment: i think modal() is bootstrap function.Include boostrap js file

Comment: modal() work out of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

it is fix.